# activate plugins on custom theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm new to Wordpress and just created my first template.

In the functions.php I have put the following code, that function what I understand should call the plugins from the plugins directory:

```
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Widgetized Area',
        'id'   => 'widgetized-area',
        'description'   => '',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget'  => '',
        'before_title'  => '',
        'after_title'   => ''
    ));

}
```

I do see all the plugins, and in the widget screen I also see the 'widgets' screen and it allows me to drag widgets into the working area.

The website itself displays the plugin's html but neither js nor css is working.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Above code that you have added in your `functions.php` is to register sidebar not to call any plugin. It do not have any connection to plugin.

You can call sidebar you added in template as follow:

```
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'widgetized-area' ) ) { 

    dynamic_sidebar( 'widgetized-area' ); 

}
```

Comment: Manesh, thanks for the response. in my template i called the dynamic_sidebar, and i see the plugins html they just don't take css or js

Comment: can you post your site url?

Comment: It seems plugin you used do not work in WordPress 3.9. I suggest you to contact plugin support team.

Comment: but i also used the addthis plugin, and that does not work also

Comment: I am sorry, I could not find out your problem just from visiting site in the browser.